# What can cause a rider in a Saddle of the Cavalier be unseated against their will?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, mount, mounted-combat

Is there any circumstance that a rider on a mount, in a saddle of the cavalier, could be unseated against their will?

Here are some possible things to consider:

- Mount is pushed (combat action), grappled, moved against or with its will.
- Rider is pushed (combat action), grappled, moved against or with its will.
  etc...
- Larger creature that can "swallow whole", either mount or rider, as a combat action.
- Teleportation magic

Answer (score 8):

#### You are knocked unconscious.

This one is obvious from the magic item description:

> you can't be dismounted against your will if you're conscious

#### "Dismount" is a game term defined in the rules for mounting and dismounting.

Here are the things from the mount rules that the Saddle of the Cavalier prevents:

> If an effect moves your mount against its will while you’re on it, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall off the mount, landing prone in a space within 5 feet of it. If you’re knocked prone while mounted, you must make the same saving throw.
>
> If your mount is knocked prone, you can use your reaction to dismount it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it.

This is what the magic item description is referring to when it says "you can't be dismounted against your will".

#### Teleportation and getting swallowed are different from being dismounted.

Neither being teleported, nor being swallowed, are covered in the rules for mounting and dismounting, *because dismounting is a specific thing defined in those rules*. The Saddle of the Cavalier will not prevent teleportation or being swallowed, because those things are not the same thing as being dismounted.

Comment: If the saddle prevents this:   **If an effect moves your mount against its will while you’re on it**, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall off the mount, landing prone in a space within 5 feet of it. If you’re knocked prone while mounted, you must make the same saving throw.  `Isn't that the result of the mount being swallowed whole, or teleporting away?`

Comment: Swallowed-whole is an effect, and it causes your mount to be moved against its will.

Comment: What about forced movement of the rider away from the mount?

Comment: @interested3rdparty Teleportation is not movement. I can see "swallowed-whole" as a sort of forced movement effect, though.

Comment: @KogarashiKaito The Teleport spell says that it instantly transports (moves) you from a to b.  It says the target must be willing.  Dismount rules state if the mount moves involuntarily.  The mount can't willingly teleport, to trigger a rider dismount, but I feel that if the mount was unwilling to be teleported, movement even via teleport (from something other than the spell Teleport) is movement.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov *The Saddle of the Cavalier will not prevent teleportation or being swallowed, because those things are not the same thing as being dismounted.*  I 100% agree with this, *but*, I feel it doesn't provide an answer to the question.   A mount **will still be swallowed, or teleported**.  The question is will the rider come along or not?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Can you provide an answer of that?  (as opposed to a comment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126830/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-interested3rdparty).